# Gedmo Doctrine Extensions Tree can't create category without a parent

Tags: forms, symfony, nested-sets, doctrine-extensions

I'm using the Gedmo Doctrine Extensions to handle Categories as a nested set.
I'm building a REST API and I have a route to create a Category.
I want to be able to create root Categories or child Categories.
Here is the entity

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @Gedmo\Tree(type="nested")
 * @ORM\Table(name="bo_categories")
 * use repository for handy tree functions
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Gedmo\Tree\Entity\Repository\NestedTreeRepository")
 */
class Category
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=64)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @Gedmo\TreeLeft
     * @ORM\Column(name="lft", type="integer")
     */
    private $lft;

    /**
     * @Gedmo\TreeLevel
     * @ORM\Column(name="lvl", type="integer")
     */
    private $lvl;

    /**
     * @Gedmo\TreeRight
     * @ORM\Column(name="rgt", type="integer")
     */
    private $rgt;

    /**
     * @Gedmo\TreeRoot
     * @ORM\Column(name="root", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $root;

    /**
     * @Gedmo\TreeParent
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="children")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    private $parent;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Category", mappedBy="parent")
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"lft" = "ASC"})
     */
    private $children;

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setParent(Category $parent = null)
    {
        $this->parent = $parent;
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return $this->parent;
    }
}
```

Here is the form

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form\Type\Classification;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class CategoryFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name')
                ->add('parent', 'entity', array(
                        'class'    => 'AppBundle:Category',
                        'property' => 'id',
                    ))
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class'      => 'AppBundle\Entity\Category',
            'csrf_protection' => false,
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'api_category';
    }
}
```

And here is the controller

```
/**
     * @Route("/create")
     * @Security("has_role('ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN')")
     * @Rest\View
     */
    public function postCreateAction(Request $request)
    {
        $categoryManager = $this->get('app.manager.category');

        $category = $categoryManager->createNew();

        $form = $this->createForm(new CategoryFormType(), $category);

        // $category->setParent(10);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {

            $categoryManager->save($category);

            return new Response('', 201);
        } else {
            return $this->view($form, 400);
        }

    }
```

If I want to create a child category, it works fine. But if I want to create a root category without removing the "parent" field in the form I get this error

`An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT b0_.id AS id0, b0_.name AS name1, b0_.lft AS lft2, b0_.lvl AS lvl3, b0_.rgt AS rgt4, b0_.root AS root5, b0_.parent_id AS parent_id6 FROM bo_categories b0_ WHERE b0_.id IN (?)' with params [""]:\n\nSQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "",
                "class": "Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException`

Why do I get this error ? Can't the "parent" value be empty/null in the form ?

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no problem `parent` being `NULL`. Your current mapping on the other hand, doesn't allow that.

First, you should modify your mapping for `$parent`

```
@ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
```

should allow `null` values:

```
@ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE", nullable=true)
```

Don't forget to run `app/console doctrine:schema:update --force` when you change your mappings!

Next, your form looks okay, but it miss one property - `empty_value`. This won't force you to choose parent category.

```
->add('parent', 'entity', array(
      'class'    => 'AppBundle:Category',
      'property' => 'id',
))
```

should be like this:

```
->add('parent', 'entity', array(
      'class'    => 'AppBundle:Category',
      'property' => 'id',
      'empty_value' => '-- Select parent --'
))
```

This should add extra option with **no** value and should be selected by default (when creating new category). Since your field is of type `entity` you will see all of your categories as well (when you need to select parent).

This should do the trick, give it a try.

Comment: I added the `nullable=true` in the mapping but that didn't change anything. I still get the same error. `schema:update` told me that there was no change in the schema (which seems logical since a many to one can be null by default, since it's a collection). And `'empty_value' => '-- Select parent --'` only applies for HTML form, and I'm building an API, so my calls are made with POSTMAN.
Thanks for your help anyway :)

Comment: I missed the API part. On a side note M:1 represents a foreign key in your table,not a collection. If you're positive that `parent` accept NULL you should be able to create root category. I will look into it later because I am on my phone.